# Can I get the number that is calling by native dialer?

Tags: android, phone-call

Can I get the number that is calling by native dialer ?

I want to show the "toast message" with information about cost per minute according to a dialing number. But I do not know how to get this number.

It could be good to have sample which show "toast message" with dialed number during of call.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it.You need to implement [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

```
public static Boolean phoneRinging = false;

public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
        phoneRinging = false;
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
        phoneRinging = false;
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
        phoneRinging = true;

        break;
    }
}
```

}

To register the listener do this:

```
        CustomPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

**Note that access to some telephony information is permission-protected. Your application won't receive updates for protected information unless it has the appropriate permissions declared in its manifest file. Where permissions apply, they are noted in the appropriate LISTEN_ flags.**